# How to insert source columnvalue with the insertion output into a new table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set of FakeIds, which are then converted to real ids on insertion. I now want to obtain the mapping of fake to real. My query is like

```
INSERT INTO Data_tbl
(days)
OUTPUT inserted.DateID, 0,source.DateID into @mappedIDs(objectId, objectTypeId, fakeId) 
SELECT  Days                            
FROM @inputTable
```

I know that Source.DateId won't work but I have put it there to so explain what I need

Comment: How are the Ids converted from fake to real?

Comment: Is `days` unique?  If so, that could be used to join the source and target after the insert to determine the mapping.

Comment: I will be sending data with fake unique ids like -1, -2 -3 and so on, once they are inserted, I need to map these to the Actual ids generated on insert in the identity column to use in further processing

Comment: @DanGuzman no its not unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

USE a **MERGE** command instead... in the OUTPUT clause you can mention the inserted and source column that you required.

Sample code is given below.

```
MERGE Data_tbl d
USING   (   SELECT  DateID,Days
             FROM @inputTable

        ) d1 ON  d.DateID = d1.DateID
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
THEN INSERT 
    ([days])
    VALUES (d1.[days])
OUTPUT  inserted.DateID, 0,d1.DateID INTO @mappedID
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick to mapping inserted data to source data when you don't pass both IDs to the destination table is tricky, you have to build your own map.  Here's my full script you can use to build your own.

First, to emulate your destination table I created a temp table, so I always put a check to see if the temp table already exists, in case I want to run the demo multiple times.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Data_tbl') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Data_tbl
```

Then I create my version of your destination table with just the two columns I need.

```
CREATE TABLE #Data_tbl (
      DateID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
    , [Days] DATE 
)
```

Then I create my table variable like you did, but I changed the column names to hopefully make things less complicated. In my output, I'm only capturing the ID created, and the day that was inserted. The day inserted is important, because that will be my key I use in my join later.

```
DECLARE @mappedIDs TABLE (
      InsertedID INT
    , [Days] DATE
)
```

Then I set up a table representing my rows to be inserted. That way you can test what happens when you insert more than one row in a batch!

```
DECLARE @inputTable TABLE (
    FakeID INT
    , [Days] DATE
)
```

Now, let's stuff a row into the source.

```
INSERT INTO @inputTable
VALUES (1, '9/2/2016')
```

Here's the insert statement.  Notice I'm only inserting the days in this example, but you could insert more if you needed to.  The output clause there is the important thing to keep the same if you're trying to build your map. You've got to collect the DateID created in your destination table, and the Days.

```
INSERT INTO #Data_tbl
([Days])
OUTPUT inserted.DateID, inserted.[Days] into @mappedIDs(InsertedID, [Days]) 
SELECT  Days                            
FROM @inputTable source
```

Now, let's show the map!  I take the inserted rows (in @mappedIDs) and join it to my source records on Days. Now I can see the mapping from FakeID to "real" ID.

```
SELECT 
    results.InsertedID, src.FakeID, src.[Days]
FROM @mappedIDs results
INNER JOIN @inputTable src
    ON results.[Days] = src.[Days]
```